When a Dell laptop is listed as Ubuntu Certified, does that include the 2-in-1 version?
Thanks for taking the time. I think this is specific to Dell laptops, as Lenovo and HP seem to use "yoga" and "x360" to indicate a model is a 2-in-1 version. Dell seems to use the same model numbers/names for both regular and 2-in-1 laptops.
For example,the spec sheet for the Latitude 7420 lists a non-touch version, a touch version, and a 2-in-1 version, all under the 7420 model number.
There are two entries for the Latitude 7420 in the Ubuntu certified database, one seems to have a touch screen, the other doesn't. Neither entry is listed as being a 2-in-1.
So, my question is: if the 2-in-1 version of a Dell laptop is certified, is it specifically labeled as the 2-in-1 version in the Ubuntu Certified database, or is it included under the entry for the regular model?
Searching for "2-in-1" in the Ubuntu Certified database returns no Dell models. If 2-in-1 models are not included under the entries for regular models, that seems like it would mean that no Dell 2-in-1s are certified?

I'm no expert, but I bet it'll be whatever devices Dell asked to be certified, and those devices only (any subsequent models brought out by Dell would need another request for certification... as certification takes time (costing money) its not usually sought by the maker/OEM who has to pay the costs; Dell in this case)

This question really isn't about Ubuntu, but about Dell hardware certification.

To answer my own question: it seems that if the 2-in-1 version of a Dell laptop is Ubuntu Certified it will specifically be listed as the 2-in-1 version. This is based on looking at the spec sheets for the Latitude 7410 and 7430, which both say the 2-in-1 version does not support Ubuntu. The spec sheet for the 7420 does not say this, but I'm assuming that is just an oversight, given that the model years on either side don't support it.
